# How to create a simple shader in unity3d and coding in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I created in my project a Shader > Standard Surface Shader named it: `TestShader`.

Then double click open it and open it in visual studio. once it opened in Visual Studio I'm getting some errors like on the first line:

> Error HLSL0029 Cannot resolve type: 'Shader'.

and more errors.

Do I need some plugin for Visual Studio? Or to set something in the unity editor to make it integrated with the Visual Studio?

```
Shader "Custom/TestShader"
{
    Properties
    {
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Glossiness ("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _Metallic ("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 200

        CGPROGRAM
        // Physically based Standard lighting model, and enable shadows on all light types
        #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows

        // Use shader model 3.0 target, to get nicer looking lighting
        #pragma target 3.0

        sampler2D _MainTex;

        struct Input
        {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
        };

        half _Glossiness;
        half _Metallic;
        fixed4 _Color;

        // Add instancing support for this shader. You need to check 'Enable Instancing' on materials that use the shader.
        // See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html for more information about instancing.
        // #pragma instancing_options assumeuniformscaling
        UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_START(Props)
            // put more per-instance properties here
        UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_END(Props)

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o)
        {
            // Albedo comes from a texture tinted by color
            fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
            o.Albedo = c.rgb;
            // Metallic and smoothness come from slider variables
            o.Metallic = _Metallic;
            o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
            o.Alpha = c.a;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Visual Studio Installer, and remove the HLSL Tools component.

[image: HLSL]

If you still need to highlight Unity shaders, you can install the ShaderlabVS extension from here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShaderlabVS2019.ShaderlabVS